# REST API: No route was found matching the URL and request method

Tags: 404-error, rest-api, routing

I'm having issues adding a custom REST API route to Wordpress.
Using my own plugin, i've registered the route as followed:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route( $namespace, 'handler_mijnenergie', array(
    'methods'   => '\WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE ',
    'callback'  => [ $this, 'handle_energie_data' ]
  ), false );
} );
```

When calling the namespace "/wp-json/watz/v1" I get a correct response in Postman that the route is shown.
[image]

However, when i try to access the route request directly, i get thrown a 404 error. So far I've tried:

- Rewriting the permalinks
- Using standard Wordpress .htaccess
- Disabling plugins
- Changing method/namespace & request
- Testing other plugin routes like Yoast or Contact Form 7 (they work)

Any idea what could be causing the issue here and what I need to alter to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of how you've defined the accepted methods:

```
'methods'   => '\WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE ',
```

You shouldn't have quotes around it. `WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE` is a string that equals `'POST'`, but by putting quotes around it you're literally setting the method as `'\WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE'`, which is not a valid HTTP method. You can see this in the response to the namespace endpoint.

Set it like this:

```
'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE
```

Or, if your file is using a PHP namespace, like this:

```
'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE
```

Or add this to the top of the file:

```
use WP_REST_Server;
```

Then make sure that when you're accessing the route directly, that you're using the correct method. If you're using `WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE` then the endpoint will only respond to `POST` requests, so `GET` requests will return a 404, which includes when you access it via the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that worked like a charm!
I learned something again today :)